# When did letter "R" lose its "rolling" pronunciation in English, and how?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation

In most Latin languages (Spanish, Portuguese, Russian...), "R" is pronounced in a "rolling" way. For example, "relájate" pronounces like "llle-la-ya-tee", "русский" pronounces like "lllus-kia". This pronunciation does not apply to English, and it's obvious that it hasn't applied to English since a long time ago. It looks like the non-rolling pronunciation in English is actually the minority. So why is this happening? And when did the change take place?

Comment: [R's are complicated in the world's languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotic_consonant). [There are some varieties of English with the trill but it's not common](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_of_English_/r/). Pronunciations drift to nearby ones. I don't think there has been posited a trilled r in Vulgar Latin or [Proto-Slavic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Slavic) or [PIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language). So I think your assumption that English lost the trill that the others kept is not founded.

Comment: @Mitch: I think Vulgar Latin is generally supposed to have had a trill realization of geminate rr at least, and possibly word-initial r too.

Comment: @sumelic How about Slavic? Or more importantly Germanic?

Comment: @Mitch: I'm not familar with the phonetic history of Slavic. If I remember correctly it has a "ruki" sound change that suggests that *r was somehow similar to *u, *k, and *i, so it may have been velarized in at least some contexts, but I don't think that indicates whether or not it was a trill. Proto-Germanic and Proto-Indo-European both seem to be too far back and to have too few relevant sound changes to be able to reconstruct the precise value of *r.

Comment: @sumelic from considering modern languages and dialects, it seems that every corner of every language has a variety of r's different from its neighbors. [WALS](http://wals.info/feature) doesn't have any inventory of trilled vs not, rhotic vs not, velar vs alveolar, etc, but informally, trilled doesn't seem to be currently all that popular in Europe among the standard ('government approved') varieties.

Comment: @Mitch: Really? But a "trill" is just the linguistic term for what English speakers usually call a "rolled" R, and I get the impression that this is viewed as the stereotypical European pronunciation of R. It's true that uvular realizations have made large gains in western European languages such as French, German and Portuguese, but the alveolar trill is still considered to be the standard pronunciation of "r" (in some positions) in Spanish and Italian, and in all of the most common Slavic languages, as well as languages of central or east Europe from other families like Greek and Hungarian.

Comment: @sumelic So you agree with the premise that (standard) English is rare in Europe for lacking a trilled 'r' currently and that it previously had it? (I don't know enough about Slavic to judge).